# inherit the home controller odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-website

I wanted to inherit the home page to add some information for login user  I followed

[odoo forms](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/odoo-v11-website-how-to-replace-home-page-139437) and [odoo mates youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htVBViZl45Q)

it is not working this is my code

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request
from odoo.addons.website_sale.controllers.main import Website
class Website_inherit(Website):
    @http.route('/', type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def index(self, **kw):
        res = super(Website_inherit, self).index(**kw)
        print("vlad work")
        
        
        return http.request.render('n_theme.name_app', data)
```